# Change between multiple states

Tags: angular

I have a component looking something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'myApp-component',
  templateUrl: './myApp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myApp.component.scss']
})
export class MyApp implements OnInit {

  myState1: boolean;
  myState2: boolean;
  myState3: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div (click)="myState1 = true; myState2 = false; myState3 = false">Button1</div>
<div (click)="myState2 = true; myState1 = false; myState3 = false">Button2</div>
<div (click)="myState3 = true; myState1 = false; myState2 = false">Button3</div>
```

So basically, when I click one, the other becomes `false` and so on, and I can use the current `true` state as I need to. As such this is not that bad, but I imagine that if I ever get more than three states (which I know I will), this will just end up being a mess.

How do I make this a bit more clean so that I can have many more states without having to worry much about the HTML being a mess ?

Comment: Instead of div use a radio input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a union type of string states/statuses stored in just one variable. This way you have a single source of truth and you only have to alter one variable to change the state. And you can check for the state very easily.

```
...
type State = 'state1' | 'state2' | 'state3'

export class MyApp implements OnInit {

  state: State;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  someFunction() {
    if (this.state === 'state1') // etc, or switch
  }
  
}
```

```
<div (click)="state = 'state1'">Button3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

state would ideally be an enum but I've used a string here for simplicity. You would probably want to enhance this by using something like localStorage to remember the state (instead of always defaulting to state1). Another (or an alternative) enhancement is that you could also pass state via queryParams to support bookmarking and link sharing.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'myApp-component',
  templateUrl: './myApp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myApp.component.scss']
})
export class MyApp {

  state = 'state1'; // or get state from storage using ... localStorage.getItem('state') || 'state1';

  updateState(state: string) {
    this.state = state;
    // execute other state change code here e.g. save new state to localStorage with ... localStorage.setItem('state', state);
  }
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<div (click)="updateState('state1')">Button1</div>
<div (click)="updateState('state2')">Button2</div>
<div (click)="updateState('state3')">Button3</div>

<!-- OPTIONAL MARKUP TO PROVE IT WORKS -->

<ng-container *ngIf="state === 'state1'>
  <div>State is the first state - YAY</div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="state === 'state2'>
  <div>State is the second state - BOO</div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="state === 'state3'>
  <div>State is the third state - COOL</div>
</ng-container>
```